# Create separated R-G-B array from loaded image

Tags: matlab

Sorry to bother, but it seem that I stuck with pretty easy task.
Simply, I want to create 3*m-by-3*n-by-3 RGB file from m-by-n-by-3 loaded image. Lets use folowing array as an example as example:

```
Image(:,:,1) = 0.5*ones(4);
Image(:,:,2) = ones(4);
Image(:,:,3) = 0.25*ones(4);
Image = uint8(255*Image); %3-D array, Red = 128, Green = 255, Blue = 64;
```

What I want to get is this:

```
ImageRGB(:,:,1) =

   128     0     0   128     0     0   128     0     0   128     0     0
   128     0     0   128     0     0   128     0     0   128     0     0
   128     0     0   128     0     0   128     0     0   128     0     0
   128     0     0   128     0     0   128     0     0   128     0     0


ImageRGB(:,:,2) =

     0   255     0     0   255     0     0   255     0     0   255     0
     0   255     0     0   255     0     0   255     0     0   255     0
     0   255     0     0   255     0     0   255     0     0   255     0
     0   255     0     0   255     0     0   255     0     0   255     0


ImageRGB(:,:,3) =

     0     0    64     0     0    64     0     0    64     0     0    64
     0     0    64     0     0    64     0     0    64     0     0    64
     0     0    64     0     0    64     0     0    64     0     0    64
     0     0    64     0     0    64     0     0    64     0     0    64
```

So far best I came up without using loops is this:

```
[i1,i2] = ndgrid(1:size(Image,1),[1:3:size(Image,2)*size(Image,3),2:3:size(Image,2)*size(Image,3),3:3:size(Image,2)*size(Image,3)]);
ImageRGB = accumarray([i1(:),i2(:),[ones(size(Image,1)*size(Image,2),1);2*ones(size(Image,1)*size(Image,2),1);3*ones(size(Image,1)*size(Image,2),1)] ],Image(:));
```

May be, there is some function I am not aware of, or more simple way to do this **WITHOUT** loops. Using them for such seemingly easy task feel just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is completely fine, but it's very hard to read. Why not just do something very simple and very easy to understand:

```
ImageRGB = zeros(4,4*3,3);
ImageRGB(:,1:3:end,1) = Image(:,:,1);
ImageRGB(:,2:3:end,2) = Image(:,:,2);
ImageRGB(:,3:3:end,3) = Image(:,:,3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is nice and easy.